# ELB non-static IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elb

If [AWS ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) does not have a static IP, doesn't that mean that if the IP changes before the client's DNS record expires, the client won't be able to access the resources pointed to by the ELB?

Or does it actually reserve the old IP for up to 24 hr (max DNS TTL) so that this will never happen?

**EDIT: for clarification:**

DNS records are cached on the client side. Eg. when client first query `*.elb.amazonaws.com`, it returns `12.34.56.78`. For subsequent queries to `*.elb.amazonaws.com`, it'd just use `12.34.56.78` instead of doing another DNS lookup (unless the DNS record expires, as dictated by TTL).

So if the internal IP of the ELB changes but the DNS record is still pointing to the old one, it'd not be able to access the resource?

Comment: TTL for ELB records is 60 seconds, and since it most often points to 2 IP addresses, it is easy to do a rolling update, without any downtime.

Comment: @DusanBajic I thought TTL is specified in the DNS manager? So the user is able to specify way longer than 60 sec.

Comment: Not for ELB, ELB DNS name is automatically created when you create load balancer.

Comment: @DusanBajic yes, but the DNS manager tells the client how long to keep that record pair of DNS name to IP address locally. So `*.elb.amazonaws.com` will resolve locally to the cached IP, until the TTL specified by the DNS manager.

Comment: Which "DNS manager" are you referring to? TTL is supplied along with IP address in response to DNS query (and for ELB DNS name you don't get to choose neither TTL nor IP address)

Comment: @DusanBajic https://i.imgur.com/mEHZNUr.png what's this TTL for? The DNS manager can be from your domain name registrar (namecheap etc) or you could transfer the nameservers to Netlify etc to manage the DNS lookup.

Comment: Oh, now I see where the confusion comes from. Take a look at this https://serverfault.com/questions/260254/what-does-the-ttl-on-a-cname-record-mean

Comment: Basically, your resolving name server _should_ cache CNAME record and save that one extra cycle during CNAME TTL time. But if you are already using AWS, you should move your domain nameserver there and utilize ALIAS records instead of CNAME.

Comment: @DusanBajic ahh I see...I'm using Netlify for hosting my naked root domain, so i can't move the DNS anywhere unless I use www for root domain. You meant Route 53 right? What's the advantage of ALIAS over CNAME in the context of ELB?

Comment: 2 main things: 1) It will allow you to have "CNAME" like functionality with your domain apex/root (which is generally [not possible](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain/613830#613830)); 2) and it will internally resolve the destination IP address and immediately respond with ip address

Comment: @DusanBajic In my case since I'm using Netlify DNS for my main website, is there still any advantage? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47845088/using-alias-for-elb-if-main-website-dns-manager-is-not-route-53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to Dusan's [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/260254/what-does-the-ttl-on-a-cname-record-mean): the user-controlled authoritative name server can only specify the TTL (which can be up to years) for the `CNAME` record `api.example.com` to `*.elb.amazon.com`, which doesn't change.

The resolving of `*.elb.amazon.com` into the actual IP `12.34.56.78` is done by Amazon's name servers, which has a TTL of 60 seconds.

Hence Amazon would only have to reserve the old IP for 60 seconds to ensure that all cached ELB IP records are valid.

Answer (score 0):

The Elastic Load Balancer service is designed to automatically detect and recover from failures of any component of the Elastic Load Balancer itself (part of that recovery can require replacing the load balancer and utilizing a new IP address)

Therefore its recommended to assign your DNS using using CNAMEs, 
if your DNS provider does not support CNAMES you could look into Route 53.

CNAME stands for Canonical Name. CNAME records can be used to alias one name to another. Elastic Load Balancer do expose the DNS name, AWS will do the internal IP address updating of ELBs etc.

Comment: For Amazon load balancers you should use ALIAS records instead of CNAMES.

Answer (score 0):

AWS ELB offers a DNS name instead of an IP address because there are more than one ELBs running behind the scene managed by AWS internally for High Availability and Fault Tolerance.

If there is a change of internal servers, AWS will make sure the internal DNS mapping happen instantaneously.

When you want to map a custom domain name to a Elastic Load Balancer, that is why you need to use a CNAME instead of the IP address because of these internal complexities.

Comment: DNS records are cached on the client side. Eg. when client first query `*. elb.amazonaws.com`, it returns `12.34.56.78`. For subsequent queries to `*. elb.amazonaws.com`, it'd just use `12.34.56.78` instead of doing another DNS lookup (unless the DNS record expires, as dictated by TTL). So if the internal IP of the ELB changes but the DNS record is still pointing to the old one, it'd not be able to access the resource?

Comment: If Route53 ALIAS records are used instead of CNAMES, the TTL is 60 seconds. A DNS query for ELB returns more than one address. Most correctly designed systems will handle this.

Comment: @Avery235 Your concerns about client side caching have some merit, because DNS TTL seems meaningless to browser implementations... but in practice I have not encountered issues here.  The addresses do not change often and there appears to be a period of time between when an address disappears from DNS and when it actually stops working.  I have not profiled this behavior extensively but I have been working on a tool to do so -- mostly out of curiosity and a desire to be aware of and understand what the platform is doing since, as I say, it has never caused an issue that I have noticed.

Comment: I think I understand the mechanics now, thanks to Dusan. See my answer above.