# Using ALIAS for ELB if main website DNS manager is not Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I use [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) to host my static site `example.com`. Since I don't want to append `www`, I have to use Netlify's DNS nameservers.

`example.com` uses API backend `api.example.com`, which is a `CNAME` record that resolves to an [ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) address `*.elb.amazonaws.com`.

So 2 DNS lookup is required: first to `example.com` then to `*.elb.amazonaws.com`.

**Alternative:**
Setup Route 53 with another custom domain `example.org` with an `ALIAS` record `api.example.org` that points to `*.elb.amazonaws.com`, and use `api.example.org` instead of `api.example.com` for `example.com`'s API endpoints, then it'd have to look up `example.com` and `api.example.org`.

Is there any performance advantage advantage choosing the alternative? Would they be similar since the only difference is it has to lookup `api.example.org` instead of `*.elb.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: Please use the officially reserved example domains, such as http://example.com and http://example.org, when formulating questions.  You're unintentionally using the names of real web sites, here.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot fixed, thanks for the guideline!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias records are better than CNAME records, because they return an IP address directly upon resolution.

Example 1:

`api.example.com` as CNAME for `*.elb.amazonaws.com`

Your browser will resolve `example.com` first, download the HTML code, then upon execution of the page, it will need to resolve `api.example.com`. When it does this, it will:

1. receive the CNAME result, then
2. need to resolve `*.elb.amazonaws.com`

So in the above, there are a total of 3 resolutions required.

Example 2:

`api.example.org` as ALIAS for `*.elb.amazonaws.com`

Your browser will resolve `example.com` first, download the HTML code, then upon execution of the page, it will need to resolve `api.example.org`. When it does this, it will:

1. receive the A result (IP address) directly

So in the above, there are a total of 2 resolutions required.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood something, if I query `api.example.com` first, then `example.com`'s IP will be returned together with it, but not the other way round.

Comment: Is there a way to use `https://*.elb.amazonaws.com` directly as API address for HTTPS sites? Since we can't get a cert for `*.elb.amazonaws.com`, that won't be possible right?

Comment: "if I query `api.example.com` first, then `example.com`'s IP will be returned together with it" ... no. One query, one result. You must always use a distinct query for each unique value. The only time you'll get multiple results is when a single DNS hostname (such as `api.example.com`) actually has multiple values itself which then the receiver would basically pick one at random (for round robin purposes).

Comment: You cannot acquire an `*.elb.amazonaws.com` cert and AWS does not provide them. So if you want HTTPS, you must use your own hostname with your own cert.

Comment: Netlify DNS has an `ALIAS` record type that seems to do the same thing, so I don't actually have to use Route 53?

Comment: Though from my tests Netlify's nameserver took longer to resolve the domain name, but that's probably because AWS has more edge location name servers.